# Почему значение указателя в одном случае NULL, а в другом - нет?

Tags: c++, указатели

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
  int data;
  Foo* next;
};

void foo1(Foo**, int);
void foo2(Foo**, int);

int main() {

  Foo *bar1 = NULL;
  Foo *bar2 = NULL;

  foo1(&bar1, 55);
  foo2(&bar2, 44);


  cout << bar1->data << endl;
  cout << bar1->next << endl; // почему введет какой-то адрес, а не NULL?

  cout << bar2->data << endl;
  cout << bar2->next << endl;


  return 0;
}

void foo1(Foo** bar, int data) {
  Foo foo;
  foo.data = data;
  foo.next = NULL;
  if( *bar == NULL) {
     *bar = &foo; 
  }
}

void foo2(Foo** bar, int data) {
  Foo *foo = new Foo;
  foo->data = data;
  foo->next = NULL;
  if( *bar == NULL) {
     *bar = foo; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Наверное, оттого что в `foo1` возвращается адрес временной переменной на стеке. После окончания работы функции этот адрес практически гарантировано будет занят другими переменными или параметрами другой функции.

Comment: Почему тогда сохраняется значение  `bar1->data`?

Comment: @jisecayeyo, совпадение. Стек не изменился в том месте просто.

Comment: Т. е. `foo` в функции `foo1` просто локальная переманная, которая "уничтожается" после завершения функции?

Comment: Да, и её адрес будет занят при первой необходимости.